# PropertyMock with changing values after every call

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to mock psycopg2 and need to handle cursor.description

```
  # run query 1
  column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
  # run query 2
  # NB cursor.description now returns different value
  column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
```

I can do this via a PropertyMock:

```
  type(fake_cursor).description = PropertyMock(return_value=descriptions[0])
```

but it doesn't solve my problem because the system under test does two queries and the description will be different for the second time.

How can I change the return value of the mock on the second call?

I tried:

```
cursor_execute_call_count = 0

def handle_cursor_execute(arg1, arg2):
    cursor_execute_call_count = cursor_execute_call_count + 1
    type(fake_cursor).description = PropertyMock(return_value=descriptions[cursor_execute_call_count])

fake_cursor.execute = Mock(side_effect=handle_cursor_execute)
```

But I get

```
E     UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor_execute_call_count' referenced before assignment
```

(That doesn't make sense to me. There must be a weird scoping issue going on.)

I did eventually get it working with this code but it seems like there must be a better way:

```
def handle_cursor_execute(arg1, arg2):
  description = descriptions.pop()
  type(fake_cursor).description = PropertyMock(return_value=description)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If what's your code is doing is that `column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]` so it's really should be as simple as puting a list in return_value of your mock.

Comment: The code does two queries. The output of description changes for every query.

Comment: That's better, I updated my answer based on your clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit based on clarification**:

I Guess you can implement an iterator:

```py
class MyDescription():

    descriptions = iter([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

    def __iter__(self):
        for description_list in self.descriptions:
            for description in description_list:
                yield description
            raise StopIteration
type(fake_cursor).description = PropertyMock(return_value=MyDescription())
```

So it will look like this:

```py
>>> z = MyDescription()
>>> [i for i in z]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [i for i in z]
[4, 5, 6]
>>> [i for i in z]
[7, 8, 9]
>>>
```